# I have to make mouse move until cursor change, but, how?

Tags: python, windows

I want to make a little script that make the mouse moves until the icon changes, but I'm not having success with it...

Here it's what I'm trying

```
def enterLink():
    mouseMove(*position[4])
    for win32gui.GetCursorInfo()[1] == 65567:
        mouseMove(*position[5])
        mouseMove(*position[4])
```

How I have to do this?
The commands are correct =/

thank you

edit:

I want the mouse cursor moving to one location to another until the area becomes a link...
For example, the page could take 5 minutes to load, so, the mouse cursor will be moving around until the page loads completely and the area become a link.

Comment: What exactly do you want to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The commands are correct =/

If they were correct, it would work...

```
for win32gui.GetCursorInfo()[1] == 65567:
```

I suggest `if`.

Comment: I want the 2 mouseMove commands from bottom loops between them, until the value gets 65567, and if doesn't do that =/

Comment: In that case you want `while` (and negate the condition since you want "until"), so `while win32gui.GetCursorInfo()[1] != 65567:`